# PHP: Resubmit/forward uploaded files stored in $_FILES to another script

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that takes as input some uploaded files and outputs a visualisation based on the processing of the files.
This script has been replaced by a new one that takes the same inputs, but outputs a new visualisation.
This all works fine.

For various reasons, I would like to keep the old visualisation accessible and switch between the 2.
If possible, I would like to change the old script as little as possible.
The naive solution would be to have a form somewhere on the new visualisation that calls the old script with the same files. Then modifications in the old script would be limited to a few path changes at worst.

To do this, I have a button somewhere on the new visualisation that calls the old script.
However, I have not found an easy way to forward the files (i.e. $_FILES) to the old script without having the user manually choose them again.
A possible workaround would be to pass the files paths using another variable, but that would mean changing the old script to process this instead of $_FILES, which I would rather avoid.

Is it possible?

---

Some skeleton code to give more context.

file_upload.html

```
    <form id="fileUpload" action="newVisualisation.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="4000000">
        <input type="file" accept=".txt" name="uploadedFiles[]" size="50" value="" multiple>
        <input type="submit" id="fileUploadSubmit" value="Upload files">
    </form>
```

newVisualisation.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
...
<?php
// Create the html for the new visualisation
createVisualisation($_FILES);
?>
...
<form id="oldVisualisation" action="oldVisualisation.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" hidden>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="4000000">
    // This obviously does nothing, is there a way to fill it with $_FILES or transmit $_FILES directly?
    <input type="file" accept=".txt" name="uploadedFiles[]" size="50" value="" multiple hidden>
    <input type="submit" id="fileUploadSubmit" value="Switch to old visualisation" />
</form>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I can do it by serialising $_FILES, posting it, then deserialising it in oldVisualisation.php.
base64 encoding/decoding is used to prevent quotes and similar from being painful.

newVisualisation.php

```
<form id="oldVisualisation" action="oldVisualisation.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" hidden>
    <input type="hidden" name="files" value='<?php echo base64_encode(serialize($_FILES)); ?>' />
    <input type="submit" id="fileUploadSubmit" value="Switch to old visualisation" />
</form>
```

oldVisualisation.php

```
// Or some other variable, it's a quite ugly to overwrite $_FILES.
$_FILES = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST["files"]));
```

I would be happy to hear if there is some other better method though.